# Angular JS + jasmine testing controller

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs, mocking, jasmine

I have a simple test in controllersSpec.coffee Angular App code:

```
describe 'Controllers', ->
  beforeEach ->
    angular.module 'app'
  describe 'MainCtrl', ->
    beforeEach inject ($controller, $rootScope) ->
      scope = $rootScope.$new()
      ctrl = $controller 'MainCtrl', $scope: scope
    it 'should be true', ->
      expect(true).toEqual(true)
```

And SpecRunner.html file for testing:

```
<html lang="eu">
  <head>
    <title>Angular Test Runner</title>
    <script src="../js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/libs/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-scenario.js" ng-autotest></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="controllersSpec.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
    var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
    jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;
        var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
    jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);
    jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
      return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
        };
    var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
      if (currentWindowOnload) {
        currentWindowOnload();
          }
          execJasmine();
        };
        function execJasmine() {
       jasmineEnv.execute();
    }
    })();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

That throw error, about '$modules' in angular-mock:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$modules' of null
    at Object.workFn (http://localhost/lolobot/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1745:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost/lolobot/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js:24673:54)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.forEach (http://localhost/lolobot/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js:9538:11)
```

Can u help me with that problem? It's my first test angular app.

Comment: What was your solution?  I am encountering this right now!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some more Angular packages included. I'm including the whole suite in my runner. I don't imagine I actually need them all, but I've tried to remove a few and had failures. Specifically, I have exactly these:

```
angular.js
angular-bootstrap.js
angular-cookies.js
angular-loader.js
angular-mocks.js
angular-resource.js
angular-sanitize.js
```

Also, in your tests, you probably want to have

```
controller = null
scope = null
```

before anything else in your `describe` block. Otherwise your controller and scope end up as local variables in your `inject` function.